# How to check all records have some value in oracle query?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have query to check some exists like:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN (exists (select * from "Customer" where length(CustomerID) > 
0) )  then 1 else 0 end val from dual
```

How do I know all records of Customer table have  length of the field(CustomerID) bigger than  3. If all records have value bigger than 3 then 1 or 0 .

Thanks in advance.
Joon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?

```
SELECT CASE WHEN MIN(LENGTH(CustomerID)) > 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Val
FROM   Customer;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Robert.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
SELECT CASE 
        WHEN COUNT(CASE 
                    WHEN LENGTH(CustomerID) > 3
                        THEN 1
                    END) = COUNT(*)
            THEN 1
        ELSE 0
        END as res
FROM Customer;
```

[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/85f55/2)